# Calling function pointer from memory location

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I am trying to call function pointer stored as a uint64_t value and pass arguments whose address are stored in a structure of uint64_t.
Here is the code.

```
double sum(double *a, long len){
    double tmp = 0;
    for(size_t i=0;i<len;i++){
        tmp += a[i];
    }
    return tmp;
}

int main(){
    long size = 1000;
    double *a = new double[size];

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        a[i] = i*1.0;
    }

    struct __attribute__ ((aligned(16))) args_t {
        double *a_func;
        long len_func;
    } args;

    args.a_func = a;
    args.len_func = size;

    double ret;

    uint64_t arg_ptr = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(&args);
    uint64_t arg_size = sizeof(args);
    uint64_t func_ptr = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(&sum);
    uint64_t func_ret = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(&ret);
// How should I call the function with arguments passed to it and get a return value?

}
```

**Moto:** I am trying to build a library which takes any function pointer, its arguments and return address where it executes the function and returns the value through return address.
Thank you! :)

Comment: Why are you trying to store a function pointer in a `uint64_t`? Why not just declare an actual pointer to the function?

Comment: @CareyGregory: I am trying to build a library which takes any function pointer and hooks the data to its arguments. Is there anyother way to do this?

Comment: Then use a `void *` as Jonathan Howard suggested. At least that will guarantee the element has the correct size and alignment to store pointers. A `uint64_t` offers no such guarantee. So your code would become `void *func_ptr = reinterpret_cast<void *>(&sum);`

Comment: @CareyGregory: How to call from func_ptr? Lets say sum is a void return and void arguments function.

Comment: If you use C++, learn at least C++11 and use lambdas and `std::function`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: The communication between library and user should happen only through uint64_t or void *. By passing arguments in a structure, the library can unwrap it. That is how it finds the number of arguments.

Comment: **If** you can use C++11, `std::function` would indeed be a good solution. However, @BasileStarynkevitch, telling people to just learn C++11 to solve their problems is often unrealistic advice since most programmers working on non-trivial projects can't pick and choose their tools, and the code base and/or external APIs they have to work with may preclude C++11. I see this advice all the time here and I usually find it pedantic and naive. I have maintenance responsibilities on three products right now and using C++11 would be impossible on two of them and difficult on the third.

Comment: But in that case you mention explicitly in the question that you need C++03 or C++98. The two major free software C++ compilers (GCC & Clang/LLVM) are today targetting by default at least C++11, and that means something.

Comment: BTW, OP should use `intptr_t` as the integer type castable to pointer. On 32 bits machines -ARM & x86- using a 64 bits integer for that is inappropriate

Comment: Why are you asking? I find your question quite unclear.... (so I downvoted it). You should at least edit your question to explain its motivations.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Don't force your answers. The question is quite clear. How do I call a function whose address is stored in an uint64_t. How much more clear do you want me to put?

Comment: It can depend upon the function signature, and it could be undefined behavior

Comment: I am aware of the undefined behaviour. I am just curious whether it is possible to do it or not. (ignoring the warnings)

Comment: No, it is not possible. You want two consecutive memory locations to go magically into two registers. You need either `asm` tricks, or `libffi` (which is doing them for you)

Comment: What I am worried is unpacking the structure as arguments to function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,
Finally I got it working.

```
double sum(double *a, long len){
    double tmp = 0;
    for(size_t i=0;i<len;i++){
        tmp += a[i];
    }
    return tmp;
}

int main(){
    long size = 1000;
    double *a = new double[size];

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        a[i] = i*1.0;
    }

    struct __attribute__ ((aligned(16))) args_t {
        double *a_func;
        long len_func;
    } args;

    args.a_func = a;
    args.len_func = size;

    double ret;

    uint64_t arg_ptr = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(&args);
    uint64_t arg_size = sizeof(args);
    uint64_t func_ptr = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(&sum);
    uint64_t func_ret = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(&ret);

    // We are trying to make a generic function caller
    size_t num_args = arg_size/8; // as elements of struct are 64bit long
    uint64_t *varg = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(arg_ptr);
    switch(num_args){
        case 2:
            {
                void* (*fun)(void*, void*) = reinterpret_cast<void* (*)(void*, void*)>(func_ptr);
                uint64_t *ret_add = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(func_ret);
                *ret_add = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(fun((void*)varg[0], (void*)varg[1]));
                break;
            }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Using switch case is not a proper way but there are not better ways to structure unrolling without using any packages or going to a latest standard. Although C++14 has a feature for passing tuple as argument list, it is not fully implemented. The switch cases can be extended to multiple arguments.

Comment: `libffi` is doing likewise, but much more generally. Actually, you miss the distinction between `double` and `long` or `void*` arguments, which are transmitted differently (most processors have floating point registers which are different of general purpose integer/pointer registers). How would you extend your scheme to handle a `long(*fun)(long,double)` function pointer? You'll probably end up with a very huge `switch` (it is not only the number of arguments which matters, but also their type)

Comment: I am casting everything to uint64_t. If you look at the code, everything is operated on uint64_t. I'll look into libffi. Seemed like a good library (hence I upvoted your answer).

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You're missing a function pointer declaration in your struct.

Also, your func_ptr and func_ret calls are not typed correctly. I wouldn't hold pointer types in a uint64_t, I suggest using a `void *` as it will be the correct length for your architecture. You definitely shouldn't hold a function pointer in a uint64_t as there is no guaranteed by the standard that a `sizeof(funcptr) == sizeof(void *)`.

```
double sum( double * a, long len )
{
    //...
    return 0.0;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    long size = 1000;
    double * a = new double[size];

    struct args_t
    {
        /** you need a ptr declaration */
        double (*func_hsa)(double *, long );
        double * a_hsa;
        long len_hsa;
    } args;

    args.func_hsa = sum;
    args.a_hsa = a;
    args.len_hsa = size;

    double ret;

    ret = args.func_hsa(args.a_hsa, args.len_hsa);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The structure should contain only args not function pointer with its signature. Can you edit your code according to the question?

Comment: @Fr34K, Where are you saving your pointer then? The original example is invalid, because you're trying to cast the address of a struct to a function pointer, which will result in a hardware trap or undefined behavior when called.

Comment: Yes. But the location of the function is present in a variable from which you can access it.

Comment: Which variable? It doesn't seem to exist in the example you posted. Please post [a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The variable is func_ptr

Answer (score 1):

> Moto: I am trying to build a library which takes any function pointer, its arguments and return address where it executes the function and returns the value through return address.

You need to know, at least dynamically at runtime, the [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature) of the called function.
Since various [application binary interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) (ABI) conventions dictate different and incompatible [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) (e.g. a `double` argument is passed in floating point register, but a `int` value is passed in some integer register, and this is processor & ABI specific and followed by compilers and linkers, etc...), you should use a specific library for that (which contains some processor & ABI specific assembler code). The [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/) is such a library and you should use it. If you can't use it, study the ABI of your implementation, e.g. [this](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) for Linux/x86-64 ABI.

> I am trying to call function pointer stored as a uint64_t value and pass arguments whose address are stored in a structure of uint64_t.

You cannot do that (without using something like the [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/) ...) in a portable way (i.e. you need some processor&ABI specific code, perhaps in assembler). You are implicitly supposing that arguments are passed on some stack, or at least thru addressable memory, and this is generally wrong, and is wrong for most [x86-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) systems: most arguments are often passed in [*processor registers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register) (and details are processor and ABI specific, so are different on Windows and on Linux).

<sup>The issue is not the function pointer, it is the calling convention and the arguments passing (and result passing).</sup>

BTW, in C and C++ the integral type castable to a pointer is `intptr_t` (from `<stdint.h>` in C, from `<cstdint>` in C++); using (and casting function pointers back and forth from/to) an `int64_t` on 32 bits architectures like ARM & x86 is not appropriate.

As I commented, if you can afford using [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) at least, [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29) (i.e. [lambda functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)) and [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) are very helpful. Read 
also about [callbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29).

See also GCC builtins for [constructing function calls](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Constructing-Calls.html).

Comment: I would give this a second best answer.